# How to create index pattern for Kibana?

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash, kibana

I am new to Kibana. I am learning it from Docs. It is written in docs that "Specify an index pattern that matches the name of one or more of your Elasticsearch indices." I am not able to understand how to create Elasticsearch indices and where to save it so as to specify an index pattern in Kibana.

Comment: Which version are you using?

Comment: For Kibana 5: https://www.elastic.co/assets/blt4ceebc7c5bd0bc0b/index-pattern.png For Kibana 4: https://www.timroes.de/images/kibana4-tutorials/index-pattern.png?5b066f

Comment: I am using : Elasticsearch 2.3.2
Logstash 2.3.2
    Kibana 4.5.0 . I have read https://github.com/gigi81/elk-windows-installer/releases and download v1.0.12. It has the above ELK Configuration.

Comment: It looks like you need some introductory material. I suggest you start reading here: https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/index.html

Answer (score 1):

To create an index:

1. Navigate to dev tools in Kibana from the left side panel

[image: dev tool option image]
2. use the below command and run it

```
PUT index_name
```

3. On the right side window a successful creation message will be seen just like in the 2nd image attached
   [index created successfully](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Guy7m.png)
4. To create an index pattern now navigate to management tab and select index pattern.
   the screen looks like this
   [image: index pattern]
5. In the step 1of 2 , type the name of the index you used in step 1. the index must get highlighted in bold as in image. select next
   [image: index pattern step]
6. Select next for step 2

7.once index pattern is created it will appear under index pattern with a * at the end , like this

[image: created index pattern]